# How do we change the value of a public variable inside a method?

Tags: java

**Here is an example:**
How to change the value of x from "*a*" to "*b*" inside a method to get the result "*b*" outside of it?

```
public class Main {

    String x = "a";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main(){
        System.out.println(x); //"a"
        String x = "b";
        System.out.println(x); //"b"
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                String x = "c"; 
                System.out.println(x); //"c"
            }
        }).start();
        System.out.println(x); //"b"
    }

    public void method(){
        System.out.println(x); //"a"
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey David, ... The possible simple solution is don't re-declare the variable `x`. Just change the value by using `x="b"`. One more thing declare `x` as static.

Comment: You could use getX() and setX(String newX) to change the value of x.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`String x = "b";` is declaring a new (local) variable, which hides the class variable of the same name. What  you need is `x = "b";`, without the type.

Answer (score 2):

By doing `String x = "b";` you are declaring a new variable but if you want to update the value of class variable you have to point on specific class variable like this:
you need to replace `String x = "b";` with `this.x = "b";`

Comment: Thank you for your solution @Sheri ! Worked perfectly fine. 